# Converting a CSV File to Typed Tuples

Tags: python, csv

I'm a java programmer just starting to learn python. My first assignment seems really strange to me and I don't know how to handle it. We were given a csv file and asked to read in the csv file and return a list of tuples representing the data, transforming each field as follows:

```
#      date: class date (see datetime module)
#      mileage: integer
#      location: string 
#      gallons: float
#      cost: float    
# Do not return a tuple for the header row.  While you can process the rawtext using string 
# functions, to receive full credit you must use Python's built in csv module.
```

I really don't know where to begin here, although I think I have figured out how to read a csv file.
This is what I have so far.

```
rows = []
with open(file_name) as f:
    rows=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
return rows
```

Edit: Adding my csv file.
http://www.filedropper.com/mustarddata

Comment: Ca you include a sample of your csv file?

Comment: And what output you expect for that sample file?

Comment: Seems each line of your file has 5 columns - you need to convert each column to its designated type (date,integer,string (no conversion needed), float,float) and create a tuple with those parsed/converted valus. Add the tuple to a list. Where is your problem? You currently only read in strings and take them as is - you do not convert anything what is the main task you need to do ...

Comment: Look into [changing-strings-to-floats-in-an-imported-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877484/changing-strings-to-floats-in-an-imported-csv) and read about strptime to convert strings into dates

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the list of tuples you generated, convert each value as required, and append it to a new final list. Alternatively, you could do it immediately as you iterate through the lines of your file:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

data=[]

with open('mustard_data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for line in csv_reader:
        # Ignore the header row
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
            continue
        else:
            # Ignore lines with missing values (or handle them otherwise if required)
            if '' not in line:  
                # Convert as appropriate
                datetime_object = datetime.strptime(line[0], '%m/%d/%Y').date()
                mileage = int(line[1])
                loc = line[2]
                gallons = float(line[3])
                cost = float(line[4].strip('$'))
                data.append((datetime_object, mileage, loc, gallons, cost))
```