# Why do plot tick labels overlap for normal data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I create a simple matpltlib plot with numpy arrays, the tick labels are well-behaved, chosen intelligently to not overlap and spaced to span the data range evenly.

However when I imported data into numpy arrays, the tick labels are a mess. It appears that it has added a tick label for *each datapoint*, rather than auto-generating a sensible scale.

Why is my data causing it to not be automatic?
How do I get MPL to do this automatically for real-world data with irregularly-spaced X/Y data?

---

"Normal" behavior:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

x = np.array(  range(1000000)  )
y = rnd.rand(1,1000000)[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
```

Resulting plot, as expected:
[image: Plot of 2 numpy arrays, sensible axes]

---

Real-world data with non-equally-spaced X-axis data, imported from file.

Snippet of data file:

```
-1900.209922,-106.022
-1900.176409,-103.902
-1900.142897,-112.337
-1900.109384,-109.252
...
```

Plotting script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

# Read CSV file
with open(r"graph.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', )
    data_read = [row for row in reader]
#end with file

d = np.array(data_read).T   # transpose

x = d[0][0:10]
y = d[1][0:10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( x, y, "." )
fig.show()
```

I get messy tick labels:
[image: collided x-tick labels]

Zoomed in, you can see it added ticks at exactly my data points:
[image: messy x-ticks, zoomed in]

---

If I change the X-data to a linear array, then it auto-ticks the x-axis, putting labels at intuitive locations (not at datapoints):

```
y = d[1][0:100]
x = range( len(y) )   # integer x-axis points

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( x, y, "." )
fig.show()
```

[image: integer x-axes]

By the way, even if I load 20,000 data points, such that the y axis spans from -106 --> -88 (in case the values were too closely spaced), the y-axis labels still collide:

```
y[-1]
Out[31]: '-88.109'

y[0]
Out[32]: '-106.022'
```

[image: 20,000 datapoints]

Ultimately I'll be loading a large number of datapoints (200,000), so need this solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely common issue and it occurs when plotting string data rather than numeric. Essentially, the csv package is reading in the data as strings rather than numbers. You can fix this by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39197736/12131013), but you have two other options.

1. Use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read in the data properly. It also has plotting methods. It is the recommended way to handle numeric csv data.
2. Convert `d` to be a numpy array of floats as shown below.

```py
# when creating d
d = np.array(data_read, dtype=float).T

# if d is already created
d = d.astype(float)
```

---

P.S. You can save figures using `plt.savefig("filename.png")` rather than taking screenshots of them.

Comment: YES! Thank you. `dtype=float` did the trick.  I will not pretend to understand why data loaded as a "string" could possibly be plotted at all, but i'll take your word for it. My script was previously taking ~5-10min to plot the data - I now realize that's because it was the rendering of 200k labels that was choking it. It is now very fast. This solved my problem AND saved me hours of plotting time. Thank you!

Comment: @Demis I'm sure there's a reason that matplotlib lets the user plot string data, but given that this is such a common issue, it would be helpful if they printed a warning about plotting string data and then included a keyword argument to turn off that warning, such as `warnstring`.

Comment: @Demis Also, as I mentioned in my answer, Pandas is the proper way to go about handling numeric csv data; using the `dtype` for numpy, in this case, is just a hot fix. If you're not familiar, you should look into Pandas. It's essentially the Excel equivalent for Python. It contains many methods for manipulating data as well as some built-in methods for plotting (using matplotlib).

Comment: I agree - I am doing that right now - I have used `pandas` with great success in the past.  The "hotfix" will at least get me somewhere useful for tonight after hours of tinkering with the slow plotting.  Thanks again.